# EF migration can't Alter(change) Datetime(DataType) column to long(bigint)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, alter-column

I use EF code first approach and altering database by **package manager console**

Trying to change column *invoiceno* Datetime to long

Add-migration "message"

**Update-Database** command returns error

```
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to bigint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to 
run this query.
```

Answer (score 0):

insert before

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```